# Ways to place n distinguishable objects in k non-distinguishable sets.

Tags: combinatorics

#### **Number of ways to divide a set of 11 distinct objects in 3 non-empty sets?**

I tried to do this and couldn't come up with a way that would work for $n$ distinct objects into $k$ sets. 
I did brute force for the problem in title. Here is my effort

Firstly number of ways 11 objects can be divided into 3 sets is 10. 
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
n_1,n_2,n_3& ways  \\ \hline
1,1,9 & 110\\ \hline
2,1,8 & 495\\ \hline
3,1,7 & 1320\\ \hline
4,1,6 &  2310\\ \hline
5,1,5 &  2272\\ \hline
2,2,7 &  2475\\ \hline
3,2,6 &  5940\\ \hline
4,2,5 &  6930\\ \hline
3,3,5 &  19800\\ \hline
4,3,4 &  11500\\ \hline
\end{array}
$$Total=53702$$

Is there a general method for this.

#### Edit:

Answer: Number of ways are given by the Stirling number of second kind $$S(n,k)=\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^{k}(-1)^{k-j}\binom{k}{j}j^n$$
This gives the answer to be [28510](http://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1292214964)

Comment: Stirling numbers?

Comment: first kind or second kind

Comment: Focusing on the statement that there are $110$ ways to divide them into $1,1,9$, that comes from $11$ ways to choose the first $1$ and $10$ ways to choose the second.  It seems strange that you care which $1$ is chosen first,or there would be $55$ ways, but not whether the $9$ is chosen first, which would give $330$ ways.  Please carefully define what you consider to be different ways here.

Comment: If $9$ are chosen first then there are $55$ ways to do it, the next ball need to be chosen among the remaining two of which there are two ways so it still comes to $110$

Comment: @RobertZ Thanks this seems to exactly solve the problem.

Comment: My point is that you seem inconsistent in caring about the order the groups are chosen.  Using five items grouped $1,1,3$ you distinguish $(1),(2),(3,4,5)$ from $(2),(1),(3,4,5)$ but not from $(3,4,5),(1),(2)$  The Stirling numbers of the second kind consider all of these equivalent so there are only $55$ groupings $1,1,9$.  We divide by $2$ for switching the order of the singletons.

Comment: @RossMillikan my answer does seem quite a bit off, but I am still not getting your point. According to me all the partitions $(n_1,n_2,n_3)$ i have made seem distinct. And then I use the formula $\binom{11}{n_1}\binom{11-n_1}{n_2}$ The order in which I pick $n_1, n_2, n_3$ shouldn't matter right. What do you see wrong with this approach?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown could you post the answer.

Comment: See my example last comment.  If you are separating five items into $1,1,3$ you would say there are $20$ ways, five to choose the first $1$ and four to choose the next.  That is why I see you saying $(1),(2),(3,4,5)$ is different from $(2),(1),(3,4,5)$.  However you do not list $3,1,1$ as a viable division, so do not count $(3,4,5),(1),(2)$.  Following the Wikipedia page $\left \{ \stackrel {11}{3} \right \}=3\left \{ \stackrel {10}{3} \right \}+\left \{ \stackrel {11}{2} \right \}=3\cdot 9330+1023=29013$  This is less than yours because of not counting switching the groups of the same size.

Comment: Ok I sort of understand. So how should I change my formula so that this is reflected. I tried to divide by two when there were two distinct number like $(1,1,9)$ that got down the answer but still not correct. There must be something wrong with how I calculate ways for $(3,1,7)$